# simplify $(a_1 + a_2 +a_3+... +a_n)^m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

How to simplify this best 
$(a_1 + a_2 +a_3+... +a_n)^m$
for 
$m=n, m<n, m>n$

I could only get 
$\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{m}{i}a_i^i\sum_{j=0}^{m-i}\binom{m-i}{j}a_j ... $

Comment: It is already as simple as it gets if you don't have other information on the $a_i$s.

Comment: they are just variable ... let's say like a and b in binomial expansion

Comment: Note that Pascal's Tetraedron, then its $4th$ dimensional analogue, then the $5th$, is a graphical way to visualise the multinomial theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplification for this type of expansion is done through the multinomial theorem. The multinomial theorem is a generalization of the binomial case to any arbitrary number of terms in the sum to be exponentiated.

The multinomial theorem is written as follows:

$$(x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_m)^n 
 = \sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n} {n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m}
  \prod_{1\le t\le m}x_{t}^{k_{t}}\ $$

Where the multinomial co-efficient is defined as:

$$  {n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m}
 = \frac{n!}{k_1!\, k_2! \cdots k_m!} $$

It may also be useful to you to note that the multinomial co-efficient is always expressible as products of binomial co-efficients *[Graham, Knuth, Patashnik, Concrete Mathematics (2nd edition)]*:

$$
{n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} = {x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m \choose x_2+\cdots+x_m}\cdots{x_{m-1}+x_m \choose x_m}
$$

A fuller explanation can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), or [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialTheorem.html)

Comment: is there any relation between $ k_1, k_2, ...  $  isn't $ k_1+k_2+ ...+k_m=n $ again going to be combination of k's??

Comment: The only relation is that the sum of all $k_i$ is equal to n. I do not believe there is an equality relationship such as $k_1>k_2$ or anything like that.

Comment: Oh ... thank you both!!

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [Multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem): 
$$(a_1 + a_2 +a_3+... +a_n)^m=\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_n=m}\frac{m!}{k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_n!}a_1^{k_1}\cdot...\cdot a_n^{k_n}$$