# Develop a multinomial algebraic expression

Tags: combinatorics

Develop $(x_1+2x_2+3x_3)^4$

I  how much elements are there? it is $4+2\choose 2$ but how do I know exactly each coefficient?

do I need to start with $ \frac{4!}{4!0!0!} $ then $ \frac{4!}{0!4!0!} $ then $ \frac{4!}{0!0!4!} $ and etc.?

Is there a formula to find all the $4+2\choose 2$ coefficients?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151611/simplify-a-1-a-2-a-3-a-nm/151615#151615, it should help you.

Comment: I just do not get this
"It may also be useful to you to note that the multinomial co-efficient is always expressible as products of binomial co-efficients *[Graham, Knuth, Patashnik, Concrete Mathematics (2nd edition)]*:

$$
{n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} = {x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m \choose x_2+\cdots+x_m}\cdots{x_{m-1}+x_m \choose x_m}
$$"    and there lays my problem I think

Answer (score 1):

I think that on the RHS of the quoted text, the $x_i$ should be $k_i$. Then consider the multinomial $$\dbinom{n}{k_1,k_2,\dotsc,k_m}.$$
We can compute this coefficient by determining the number of ways to place the $k_1$ objects of the first kind and multiplying by the number of ways to place the remaining objects. But this is just
\begin{align}
  \dbinom{n}{k_1}\cdot\dbinom{n-k_1}{k_2,k_3,\dotsc, k_n}
     &= \dbinom{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m}{k_1}\cdot \dbinom{k_2+\cdots+k_m}{k_2, k_3, \dotsc, k_n} \\
     &= \dbinom{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m}{k_2+\cdots+k_m}
       \cdot \dbinom{k_2+\cdots+k_m}{k_2, k_3, \dotsc, k_n}.
\end{align}
Now proceed by induction to establish the formula you quoted.

Next, considering $(x_1+2x_2+3x_3)^4$, every term in the expansion is of the form $x_1^{i_1}(2x_2)^{i_2}(3x_3)^{i_3}$ where $i_1+i_2+i_3 = 4$. The number of ways to get $x_1^{i_1}(2x_2)^{i_2}(3x_3)^{i_3}$ is $\binom{4}{i_1,i_2,i_3}$, so the coefficient of $x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}x_3^{i_3}$ is $1^{i_1}2^{i_2}3^{i_3} \binom{4}{i_1,i_2,i_3}$.

Comment: I tried it on a smaller problem $(x+y+z)^2$ so the first one was $ \frac{2!}{2!0!0!} $ then $ \frac{2!}{1!1!0!} $ then $ \frac{2!}{0!1!1!} $

I try to find a formula